# Leer una secuencia de números y mostrar diagrama de barras con la frecuencia de aparición

Tags: c++

Necesito diseñar en C++ un programa al que le introduces una secuencia de números del 0 al 9 y te muestra en pantalla un diagrama de barras con un asterisco cada vez que el número aparezca. Tengo claro como crear el diagrama pero no como rellenarlo con cada número que lea. Quizá se pueda hacer con arrays pero no es el objetivo.

Ejemplo (así hasta 9):

0:**

1:*****

2:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int FINAL = -1;
const char contador = '*';

int main()
{
   int primer_numero = 0; // corresponde al primer número de la secuencia
   int siguiente_numero = 0; // corresponde a todos los siguientes números de la secuencia

   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

   cout << "Escribe secuencia de números (" << FINAL << "-> Acabar): " << endl;
   cin >> primer_numero;
   
   while(primer_numero != FINAL){
        cin >> siguiente_numero
        
        for(int i = -1; i < 9; i++){
            cout << i + 1 << " : " << "" << endl;
   }
   }

}
```

Comment: Y si vas contando para cada número y después pintas una cantidad de `*` que represente ese conteo para cada dígito?

Answer (score 0):

Si son números del cero al nueve, crea una formación de enteros para contarlos:

```
int recuentos[10]{};
```

Después por cada número leído de la consola aumentas el recuento correspondiente:

```
int numero = FINAL;

do {
    cin >> numero;

    ++recuentos[numero - 1];
} while (numero != FINAL);
```

Finalmente, puedes imprimir tu diagrama de barras:

```
for (int numero = 0; numero != 10; ++numero)
    cout << numero + 1 << ": " << string(recuentos[numero], '*') << '\n';
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDdSsQwEIWvO08xrhdtrYWNP6zYWvBGEMQXWHsR0rgG2knJDwpLn70mbqXo1XC@nDlniBjHUvScDvN8rkj0vpNYK22dkXxoYGWBKDo0AIocDlxRlsMREm8DReKDtCMXEq3rKoBEaLJOfo0Go/3p@fXxBR@wZBUkERgpvCSn7Z5t2@O0UPKDNDr4fvwxptMYOhKhCJtmeY88KYo1YlkrkbUhaMLPD9VLzBZ8tsTlce9dG8z@VG0rXI0sqKI46Tz2au@wrn8dBbKoNve4ifP0I9n/Q9pLTC/SPDrSN0pjrZHOGwpdMM0zAwZXcA23cAc3Ye6C3kHJ4Bs)</kbd>.